# Is it possible to make use of a specific AD group for authentication?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I need to access Sharepoint on premises site with 'windows based authentication' and using a specific Active Directory Group. 
Only the members in that group should have permissions to access into that site.

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to reference the AD Group in the permissions. Type in the group name instead of the username, you can then assign it permissions in the same way as normal.